# latexdiff "2 and only 2 non-option arguments required"

Tags: latexdiff

I installed *latexdiff* and ran `latexdiff C:\Users\Alf\OneDrive - Blabla\Git\document\main.tex > C:\Users\Alf\OneDrive - Blabla\Git\document-revised\main.tex`. However, I rceive the following error:

```
2 and only 2 non-option arguments required.  Write latexdiff -h to get help
C:\texlive\2022\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:915: command failed with exit code 2:
perl.exe c:\texlive\2022\texmf-dist\scripts\latexdiff\latexdiff.pl C:\Users\Alf\OneDrive - Blabla\Git\document\main.tex  - Blabla\Git\document-revised\main.tex
```

I believe I installed *latexdiff* successfully because
`latexdiff -h` returns:

```
Usage: c:\texlive\2022\texmf-dist\scripts\latexdiff\latexdiff.pl [options] old.tex new.tex > diff.tex

Compares two latex files and writes tex code to stdout, which has the same format as new.tex but
has all changes relative to old.tex marked up or commented. Note that old.tex and new.tex need to
be real files (not pipes or similar) as they are opened twice.
...
...
...
```

Maybe the spaces in the file paths cause a problem?

Comment: Yes, the spaces are guaranteed to cause problems, try surrounding the file names with quotes.

Comment: Also the `>` before the second file name is wrong. Your command call should be `latexdiff "C:\Users\Alf\OneDrive - Blabla\Git\document\main.tex" "C:\Users\Alf\OneDrive - Blabla\Git\document-revised\main.tex"`, then you get the results onto the command line as output. The `>` redirects the output into a file, so you could also use `latexdiff "C:\Users\Alf\OneDrive - Blabla\Git\document\main.tex" "C:\Users\Alf\OneDrive - Blabla\Git\document-revised\main.tex" > differences.tex` to get the results into a file called `differences.tex`.

Comment: Thank you. Your comments already helped me. I got the `>` from https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/Using_Latexdiff_For_Marking_Changes_To_Tex_Documents. It seems it works if I add quotes. However, I am still searching for the PDF output.

Comment: There is no immediate PDF output, it creates the contents of a TeX file, you can compile that file to get a PDF, iirc.

Comment: If you take a close look at that Overleaf article, it also uses two files, and then `> diff.tex` (with `diff.tex` being an output file, no input file; the `>` notation is not part of `latexdiff` but is a feature of your shell/command line).

Comment: OK, thanks. Seems to have worked. Now I have to figure out how to make it work when I have multiple subfiles. I have already searched StackExchange and it seems to be tricky. Thanks everyone for your helpful comments!

Comment: Note that latexdiff-vc is a wrapper script that can integrate the latexdiff run with actual pdf generation. With subfiles have a look at flatten option. It all depends on your setup, though.